# If sleep, join function throws an Interrupted exception then why catch block doesn't catch them?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

Here is join function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t3");

    t1.start();

    //start second thread after waiting for 2 seconds or if it's dead
    try {
        t1.join(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("In catch");
    }
    t2.start();
```

As we know that we have to put join function (and sleep function) in try-catch block then when join function throw an InterruptedException , why `In catch` is not printing?
What is a logic behind it?

Comment: Because it isn't being interrupted, so it isn't throwing the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `throws` in java is that they *can* throw, doesn't say they *have to* throw.

The purpose of the exception throwing and catching mechanism is to allow you to handle exceptions if they happen, it does not mean they will always happen